# MySQL join table as nested array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Suppose we have these 2 following tables:

`reservations` table: `id, time, user_id`

`users` table: `id, name`

When selecting reservations, how can I get the following output on pure MySQL **without querying for the "user" manually on php for each reservation?**

Because it gets really slow when looping through thousands of reservations.

```
{
 id: 1,
 time: "123456789",
 user_id: 321,
 user: {
        id: 321,
        name: John Doe
       }
}
```

Comment: Simple JOIN should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JOIN`:

```
-- could be wrapped with JSON_ARRAYAGG if needed
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', r.id,
                   'time', r.time,
                   'user_id', r.user_id,
                   'user', JSON_OBJECT('id', u.id, 'name', u.name)
       ) AS result
FROM reservations r
JOIN users u
  ON r.user_id = u.id
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=196f1513c6141dc9d8c3a96e4cfd9902)**

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get a similar result while avoiding having to type every column name and just use the asterisk (*)? Like `SELECT reservations.*, users.* ...`

Comment: @John Glad I could help. As for `SELECT *` I am not aware of such functionality for MySQL

Comment: OK then, I just made a PHP function that loops all column names of the table that I fetch using `"DESCRIBE $tableName"`  and returns a string to fill JSON_OBJECT() parameters. Helps me avoid typing 50 column names in there :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage to a nested structure.  Simply return the columns you want:

```
select r.*, u.name as user_name
from reservation r join
     user u
     on r.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: What if both tables have an "id" column, there will be overwriting unless I specify different names using "as" keyword.  And if there are too many columns this will become a burden. That's why I want to keep the default names for columns and keep user columns separate in another array, preferably using (*) symbol while selecting.

Comment: @John . . . The `id` column is the same due to the `JOIN` condition.  It is redundant to return it twice.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the data you want with a join.

```
SELECT reservations.id, reservations.time, reservations.user_id, users.name FROM reservations LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = reservations.user_id
```

Comment: This is basic joining. this will give data on the same level, not as a nested array.